# "context instance" for a XElement linq to XML query using a where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I want to return a list of string values from an XElement collection and I get this error when constructing my code and don't see what I'm missing.
[image]

Here's a section of the class I've written concering the problem:

```
private XElement _viewConfig;

public ViewConfiguration(XElement vconfig)
{

    _viewConfig = vconfig;
}

public List<string> visibleSensors()
{

    IEnumerable<string> sensors = (from el in _viewConfig
                                   where el.Attribute("type").Value == "valueModule"
                                         && el.Element.Attribute("visible") = true
                                   select el.Element.Attribute("name").Value);

    return sensors.ToList<string>();
}
```

The XElement collection is of the form

```
<module name="temperature" type="valueModule" visible="true"></module>
<module name="lightIntensity" type="valueModule" visible="true"></module>
<module name="batteryCharge" type="valueModule" visible="true"></module>
<module name="VsolarCells" type="valueModule" visible="false"></module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `XElement` is not an `IEnumerable` therefore the first line `from el in _viewConfig` is not valid. If this is coming from a valid XML file, I presume the `<module>` elements are contained inside a parent element (e.g., `<modules>`). If you make `_viewConfig` to point to `modules` then the following will work:

```
IEnumerable<string> sensors = (
    from el in _viewConfig.Elements()
    where el.Attribute("type").Value == "valueModule"
          && el.Attribute("visible").Value == "true"
    select el.Attribute("name").Value);
```

Also note that type of `el` is `XElement`, therefore it doesn't have a property called `Element` which I also removed from above (along with a few syntax errors that I had to fix: usage of `==` instead of `=` for comparison, and using string literal `"true"` instead of boolean `true` to compare the value of an attribute textual value).

Comment: thanks. I'll start incorporating and finish fleshing out the system.